# How would I determine the number of solutions for the sum of this number?

Tags: probability, statistics, discrete-mathematics, permutations

We're given the following equation:

$$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 = 20$$

I know that the simple amount of solutions to this is $\binom{5+20-1}{5-1}$, but for the following questions I'm slightly more confused. How would I find the number of solutions for these?

Note that $x_i$ must be non-negative.

a) So $x_i\geq  1$ for $1 \leq i \leq 5$.

b) So $x_i\geq 2$ for $i=1,2$ and $x_i\geq 3$ for $i=3,4,5$.

c) So $x_3  < 12$.

I'm just really confused how I'd do it with restrictions.

I know the formula for just the general number of solutions without any restrictions is $\binom{n + k - 1}{n - 1}$ but how would I apply that WITH restrictions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(b) You want the number of solutions of $$x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4+x_5=20\tag{1}$$ in non-negative integers satisfying $x_1,x_2\ge 2$ and $x_3,x_4,x_5\ge 3$. Let

$$\begin{align*}
&y_1=x_1-2,\\
&y_2=x_2-2,\\
&y_3=x_3-3,\\
&y_4=x_4-3,\text{ and}\\
&y_5=x_5-3\;.
\end{align*}$$

Then $\langle x_1,\dots,x_5\rangle$ is a solution to $(1)$ meeting the extra conditions if and only if $\langle y_1,\dots,y_5\rangle$ is a solution in non-negative integers to

$$y_1+y_2+y_3+y_4+y_5=7\;.\tag{2}$$

If you’ve seen the interpretation of the original problem as counting the number of ways to put $20$ indistinguishable balls into $5$ distinguishable boxes subject to the condition that the first two boxes each contain at least $2$ balls and the others at least $3$, the new problem is what you get if you put the minimum requirement into each box and then ask how many ways there are to distribute the remaining $7$ balls **without** any restrictions.

Now you can use the formula that you know for the unrestricted case to get a total of $$\binom{7+5-1}{5-1}=\binom{11}4$$ solutions.

You can use the same basic technique to solve (a) or any other such problem when the restrictions are all **lower** bounds.

For (c) and other problems with **upper** bounds you’ll want an [inclusion-exclusion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) argument. In this problem it’s not at all bad. First count the number of unrestricted solutions, and then subtract the number of ‘bad’ solutions, i.e., the number that have at $x_3\ge 12$. Note that counting these ‘bad’ solutions is a problem with lower bounds, so you now know how to handle it. The problem would be a bit messy if it were possible to violate more than one upper bound, but it’s not, since you have only one upper bound to worry about.

Comment: I'm confused for (c). Would I not just do $all - (x_3 >= 12)$? I thought the inclusion-exclusion principle applied to the union of two sets. If I did the union of all and $x_3 >= 12$ would I not just get all, as all encompasses the other ones?

Comment: @Doug: In this $x_3\ge12$ is the only case that needs to be excluded, so it does boil down to subtracting these from the total; that’s exactly what I suggested. But this is a very simple example of an inclusion-exclusion argument; it’s just that all of the correction terms other than the $x_3\ge12$ one are zero. (Inclusion-exclusion is by no means limited to unions of **two** sets.) For a more general example in which more calculation is needed, see my answer to [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/120322/12042).

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

If you use [stars and bars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29) to develop your original expression then (a) and (b) use essentially the same method except that some stars are stuck next to a bar (or the start) and so can come out of the calculation.

For (c), do the same thing to calculate the number of solution with the restriction $x_3 \ge 12$, and combine this with your original expression.