# How many ways to distribute $k$ indistinguishable balls over $m$ of $n$ distinguishable bins of finite capacity $l$?

Tags: combinatorics

Lets assume the non-trivial case $k < l \cdot m$. Each bin can receive a maximum of $l$ balls. I need distribute $k$ balls over $n$ bins so that some $m < n$ bins are occupied (not necessarily completely) and other $(n-m)$ remain empty. How many ways exist to do such distribution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you can select the non-empty bins in $\binom{m}{n}$ ways. So the remaining problem is to figure out how to distribute $k$ balls among $m$ bins win none getting more than $l$.

By [stars and bars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29) there are $\binom{k - 1}{m - 1}$ ways to distribute $k$ balls into $m$ bins with none empty. But this disregards the cases where some bins have more than $l$ balls. This in turn can be handled by the [principle of inclusion and exclusion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle), considering the different sets as the solutions that violate 1, 2, ... of the constraints. Say the first bin has more than $l$ balls. Add $l$ balls to the first bin, you still have to distribute $k - l$ balls among all $m$ bins (overfilling bin number 1) so that no bin is empty, which can be done in $\binom{k - l - 1}{m - 1}$ ways. But the bin violating the constraint can be selected in $\binom{m}{1}$ ways. In all, adding in the factor given at the beginning:
$$
\binom{n}{m} \sum_{j \ge 0} (-1)^j \binom{m}{j} \binom{k - j l - 1}{m - 1}
$$

Comment: Can you kindly explain, why $\binom{k-jl-1}{m-1}$ and not $\binom{k-jl-1}{m-j-1}$?

Comment: Just a small typo in your answer. Add $l$ balls to first bin, one have to distribute $k-l$ balls (instead of "$m-l$ units").

Comment: Just to improve your answer, the upper limit of sum is $\lfloor \frac{k}{l} \rfloor-1$.

Comment: @PiotrSemenov, the upper limit is inconsecuential as eventually the binomial coefficients are zero. Not to have to worry about limits helps inmensely when fumbling around with sums.

Comment: sure, I specified the upper limit just to see the finite summation. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: In the last expression $\binom{k - j l - 1}{m - 1}$ shall be replaced with $\binom{k - j (l+1)+m - 1}{m - 1}$.