# Number of ways to distribute indistinguishable balls into distinguishable boxes of given size

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

I need to find a formula for the total number of ways to distribute $N$ indistinguishable balls into $k$ distinguishable boxes of size $S\leq N$ (the cases with empty boxes are allowed). So I mean that the maximum number of balls that we can put in each box is $S$, while the minimum number is zero.

In the case $S=N$ the result should be:

\begin{equation}
\binom{N+k-1}{N}
\end{equation}

Do you know the formula for the general case? Thanks in advance!

P.S.: something similar can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/665178/how-many-ways-to-distribute-k-indistinguishable-balls-over-m-of-n-distingu).

Comment: Perhaps you can find the answer in a book that I studied some time ago: "Combinatorial Mathematics" by N. Vilenkin.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use generating functions. For each of the boxes the alternatives are represented by:
$$
1 + z + z^2 + \cdots + z^S = \frac{1 - z^{S + 1}}{1 - z}
$$
To have $N$ balls in the the $k$ boxes is the coefficient of $z^N$:
\begin{align}
[z^N] \left( \frac{1 - z^{S + 1}}{1 - z} \right)^k
  &= [z^N] (1 - z^{S + 1})^k \cdot \sum_{r \ge 0} (-1)^r \binom{-k}{r} z^r \\
  &= [z^N] (1 - z^{S + 1})^k \cdot \sum_{r \ge 0} \binom{r + k - 1}{k - 1} z^r
\end{align}
When $N \le S$ this gives the result cited; otherwise it gives a (finite) formula in terms of binomial coefficients. Nothing simple, I'm afraid.

EDIT:

Since:

$$
\left(1-z^{S+1}\right)^{k}=\sum_{j=0}^{k}\left(-1\right)^{j}\binom{k}{j}z^{\left(S+1\right)j}
$$

then the coefficient of $z^N$ in the expression is:

$$
\sum_{\begin{array}{c}
\left(S+1\right)j+r=N\\
r\geq0,\,0\leq j\leq k
\end{array}}\left(-1\right)^{j}\binom{k}{j}\binom{r+k-1}{k-1}
$$
Observing that given $r$, we can express $j = \lfloor (N - r) / (S + 1) \rfloor$ we get the rather horrible:
$$
\sum_{r \ge 0} (-1)^{\left\lfloor \frac{N - r}{S + 1} \right\rfloor}
    \binom{r + k - 1}{k - 1} 
    \binom{k}{\left\lfloor \frac{N - r}{S + 1} \right\rfloor}
$$

Comment: Many thanks vonbrand. I tried to find the final formula of the coefficient. Is this what you mean? Moreover, when you say $N\geq S$ at the end of your post, probably you mean $N=S$.

Comment: @user2983638, yes. And you are right, the sign is wrong. Fixing.

Comment: In the second to the last expression I would suggest to express   $r$ via $j$ and not the reverse. In this case the final expression would be 1) correct and 2) nice looking and rather self-explanatory.

Answer (score 0):

Since the boxes are distinguishable, when $S=N$ I think we could just multiply $\binom{N+k-1}{N}$ by $k!$ to get the desired answer.

Not sure about the case $S<N$, yet.