# Number of ways to distribute M balls into N boxes with limited size V

Tags: combinatorics, combinations, balls-in-bins

I am trying to figure out the number of ways to distribute *M* distinguishable balls into *N* distinguishable boxes, each box can at most accommodate *V* balls and the boxes can be empty.

I did my research and found some [related posts](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/818526/ways-of-distributing-n-balls-among-k-boxes-each-box-containing-l-leq-x-i). However, I don't understand well why the generating function works for the cases mentioned in the posts. It seems somehow weird for me to introduce an variable *z* to solve the problem.

In addition, the existing posts discuss the case where only the boxes are distinguishable. This is different from my problem. Does anyone know if there is a known solution for this general problem?

Thank you so much!

Comment: We want to find a sequence of values $a_0,a_1,a_2,\dots$  If we formally represent this as $a_0+a_1z+a_2z^2+\dots$ it may allow us to use methods from algebra and analysis to compute the $a_k$ values, or at least to determine some of their properties, like how fats they grow.  With $V=2$, your problem should be easy.  How far can you get with it?

Comment: I see. The reason that we can use a0+a1z+...  is that the problem in the related post can be regarded as a0+a1+a2+...,  Is it correct?  
Also, I think the original problem assume a indistinguishable balls. Is the function: a0+a1+a2+... still applicable in this problem, where the balls are also distinguishable?

Comment: You still don't understand generating functions, or you're typing carelessly.  We want the individual $a_k$ values, not their sum.  When the balls are distinguishable, I don't know how to do it with generating functions. That doesn't mean there isn't a way, but you don't need them when $V=2$.  Suppose $b_2$ buckets get $2$ balls and $b_1$ get $1$ ball.  What are the possible values of $b_2$ and $b_1$?  How many possibilities are there with these values? (Look at the first part of https://www2.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/gfology2.pdf for an explanation of generating functions.)

Comment: After reading the material and watching some videos, I think I got the point. There is some shared properties between the generating functions and the combinatorics. The individual ak can implies the number of combinations when there is at most k balls in a box. Therefore, for bucket b2, the generating function should be x0+x1+x2. Similarly, the generating function for b1 is x0+x1, and (x0+x1+x2)(x0+x1) indicates the all combinations. For example, x0*x0 implies that b1 and b2 are empty and x0*x1 indicates b1 is empty and b2 gets 1 ball.

Answer (score 1):

You can find values by recursion.

Let $f(n_0,n_1,n_2,\ldots,n_V)$ be the number of boxes with $0,1,2,\ldots$ items, where $\sum n_i =N$ and each $n_i \ge 0$

Then $$f(n_0,n_1,n_2,\ldots,n_V) \\= n_0 f(n_0-1,n_1+1,n_2,\ldots,n_V) + n_1 f(n_0,n_1-1,n_2+1,\ldots,n_V) + \\ \ldots + n_{V-1}f(n_0,n_1,n_2,\ldots,n_{V-1}-1,n_V+1)$$

starting with $f(N,0,0,\ldots,0)=1$ and $f(n_0,0,0,\ldots,0)=0$ for $n_0\not =N$.  You want those cases representing $M$ balls, i.e. $$\sum\limits_{\sum\limits _j j\, n_j = M}  f(n_0,n_1,n_2,\ldots,n_V)$$

For $V=2$, this gives the values in [OEIS A089975](https://oeis.org/A089975), which gives various formulae and a link to [a related paper](http://capone.mtsu.edu/dwalsh/WIDTH_2.pdf)