# Upper bound on number of ways to place $n$ indistinguishable objects into $k$ distinguishable intervals of size $s$

Tags: combinatorics

I need a simple, but tight upper bound on the number of ways to distribute some $n$ indistinguishable objects among $k$ distinguishable boxes of size $s$. The formula for this quantity is absolutely horrible; you can find it here:

[Number of ways to distribute indistinguishable balls into distinguishable boxes of given size](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/707996/number-of-ways-to-distribute-indistinguishable-balls-into-distinguishable-boxes)

I need to do some calculations with it, nonetheless. Can anybody give me some upper bounds, which aren't too loose? I would really appreciate it!