# How to distribute 3 groups of 10 indistinguishable objects into 4 distinguishable boxes of maximum size 5

Tags: combinatorics

I have a problem where I need to find all possible ways to distribute objects into $4$ distinguishable boxes with a maximum size of $5$ (boxes can be empty). The objects are drawn from three groups: each group containing 10 indistinguishable objects.

Currently, I know how to distribute n indistinguishable objects into k distinguishable boxes using C(k+n -1, n). However, my problem deals with three different groups of indistinguishable objects and limits the boxes to a maximum size of $5$.

Comment: How did you approach the problem? Edit that into the question.

Comment: Does the order of object in the box matter ?

Comment: Does this answer your question :https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/707996/number-of-ways-to-distribute-indistinguishable-balls-into-distinguishable-boxes

Comment: Thanks for your reply! The referred question is indeed similar to my problem, however, in my problem, I have three sets of N indistinguishable balls.

Comment: The order of the objects in the boxes does not matter.

Comment: I  take it that there are some objects left over?  4X5=20 , 3X10=30 
And I presume that one "distribution" would be to do nothing and leave the boxes empty?

Comment: I think with a couple of steps added you can use: 
 https://stats.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Probability_Theory/Book%3A_Probability_Mathematical_Statistics_and_Stochastic_Processes_(Siegrist)/12%3A_Finite_Sampling_Models/12.03%3A_The_Multivariate_Hypergeometric_Distribution  
I would add a fourth type of objects to fill out the targets to 5,  and add an intermediate bucket; that I would fill and subsequently distribute to the four targets.