# How many ways to place n distingusishable balls into m distinguishable bins of size s?

Tags: combinatorics

Let there be $n$ distinguishable balls and $m$ distinguishable bins, each bin of size $s$, that is, we cannot place more than $s$ balls into it.
How many possibilites are there to place the balls into the bins?

Comment: Here is an equivalent question with a nice answer: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/665178/how-many-ways-to-distribute-k-indistinguishable-balls-over-m-of-n-distingu?lq=1

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using  species and generating functions. If some bins
are allowed to remain empty the species is

$$\mathfrak{S}_{=m}(\mathfrak{P}_{\le s}(\mathcal{Z})).$$

This gives the generating function
$$P(z) = \left(\sum_{k=0}^s \frac{z^k}{k!}\right)^m$$

and the closed formula
$$p_{n,m,s} =
n! [z^n] \left(\sum_{k=0}^s \frac{z^k}{k!}\right)^m.$$

If no bins are allowed to remain empty the species is

$$\mathfrak{S}_{=m}(\mathfrak{P}_{1\le\cdot\le s}(\mathcal{Z})).$$

This gives the generating function
$$Q(z) = \left(\sum_{k=1}^s \frac{z^k}{k!}\right)^m$$

and the closed formula
$$q_{n,m,s} =
n! [z^n] \left(\sum_{k=1}^s \frac{z^k}{k!}\right)^m.$$

The  following Maple  code  implements a  brute  force calculation  to
verify these values and the generating functions as well.

```
P := proc(n, m, s) n!*coeftayl(add(z^k/k!, k=0..s)^m, z=0, n); end;
Q := proc(n, m, s) n!*coeftayl(add(z^k/k!, k=1..s)^m, z=0, n); end;

P_ex :=
proc(n, m, s)
    option remember;
    local ind, d, ms, k, res, pos;

    res := 0;

    if m = 1 then
        if n <= s then res := res + 1 fi;
        return res;
    fi;

    for ind from m^(n+1) to m^(n+1)+m^n-1 do
        d := convert(ind, base, m);
        ms := convert([seq(d[k], k=1..n)], multiset);

        for pos to nops(ms) do
            if ms[pos][2] > s then
                break;
            fi;
        od;

        if pos = nops(ms)+1 then
            res := res + 1;
        fi;
    od;

    res;
end;


Q_ex :=
proc(n, m, s)
    option remember;
    local ind, d, ms, k, res, pos;

    res := 0;

    if m = 1 then
        if n <= s then res := res + 1 fi;
        return res;
    fi;

    for ind from m^(n+1) to m^(n+1)+m^n-1 do
        d := convert(ind, base, m);
        ms := convert([seq(d[k], k=1..n)], multiset);

        for pos to nops(ms) do
            if ms[pos][2] > s then
                break;
            fi;
        od;

        if pos = nops(ms)+1 and nops(ms) = m then
            res := res + 1;
        fi;
    od;

    res;
end;
```

I was not able to find OEIS entries for these.

Comment: Thank you. Can you explain, how I might apply the closed formula, i.e. what the parameter z stands for, exactly? I'm sorry if this is a really stupid question.

Comment: The above might not be suitable for a first combinatorics course. Maybe someone from the set of experts on MSE will post an elementary derivation. If you want to understand the meaning of the parameter $z$ and the concept of generating functions there is this Wikipedia article on [Symbolic / Analytic Combinatorics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_combinatorics).

Comment: It would be very helpful if you could post the coefficient that I need to compute this quantity.

Comment: The two functions at the top of the Maple code namely **P** and **Q** will instantly produce the answer for any $n,m$ and $s$. Consult these to see how to input the formula into a CAS. Any one of the major CAS can do this and MSE is likely to have contributors that use them.