# Relation of relative numbers of (restricted) ways to distribute identical / distinct objects into distinct bins

Tags: combinatorics, combinations, generating-functions, integer-partitions, balls-in-bins

If want to know if the following inequality holds for general values of $s \leq n \ll m$.

$$\frac{C_0(n,m,s)}{C_0(n,m)} \leq \frac{p(n,m,s)}{m^n}$$

$C_0(n,m) = \binom{n+m-1}{m-1}$ is the [number of weak integer compositions of $n$ into $m$ parts (without restriction)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_%28combinatorics%29#Number_of_compositions). In other words, it's the number of ways to distribute $n$ identical objects into $m$ distinct bins.

$C_0(n,m,s) = \sum_{j=0}^m (-1)^j \binom{m}{j}\binom{n+m-j(s+1)-1}{m-1}$ is the [number of weak integer compositions of $n$ into $m$ parts with restricted part size $s$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1598696/what-is-the-number-of-weak-compositions-of-n-with-k-parts-and-restricted-size-of). In other words, it's the number of ways to distribute $n$ identical objects into $m$ distinct bins, where each bin has capacity $s$.

$m^n$ is the number of strings of length $n$ over an alphabet of $m$ symbols. In other words, it's the number of ways to distribute $n$ distinct objects into $m$ distinct bins.

$p(n,m,s) = n![z^n]\left(\sum_{j=0}^s \frac{z^j}{k!}\right)^m = \sum\limits_{\substack{k_1 + \cdots + k_m=n\\0\leq k_i \leq s}} \binom{n}{k_1\cdots k_m}$ is the number of strings of length $n$ over an alphabet of $m$ symbols, such that  each symbol occurs at most $s$ times in each string. In other words, it's the [number of ways to distribute $n$ distinct objects into $m$ distinct bins, where each bin has capacity $s$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/975503/how-many-ways-to-place-n-distingusishable-balls-into-m-distinct-bins-of-s).

Is this a known combinatorial problem? Does anyone know a source with the proof or disproof? What might be a suitable approach to prove it?

I verified the inequality algorithmically for $2 \leq m \leq 14$ and $1 \leq n \leq \lfloor \frac{m}{2} \rfloor$ and $1 \leq s \leq n$.