# Distinct ways to put $N$ balls in $M$ boxes such that there is no more than $K$ balls in each box?

Tags: combinatorics

The question is: in how many different ways can I put $N$ indistinguishable balls into $M$ distinguishable boxes such that each box contains no more than $K$ balls it it?

A more general problem: if $K$ is different for different boxes, $K_i$ for the box $i$, $i=1,...,M$.

I tried to find a way to use "stars and bars" method here, but didn't succeed. I would be grateful if anyone could explain how to solve such a task or provide a reference.

Comment: I swear I’ve seen this question asked a few times on this site recently

Comment: [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/120322/distribute-n-objects-to-k-boxes-such-that-no-box-has-more-than-c-objects-i/120327#120327) I gave a thorough answer to the first problem. In [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/553960/extended-stars-and-bars-problemwhere-the-upper-limit-of-the-variable-is-bounded/554237#554237) Marc van Leeuwen uses generating functions to deal with both problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $a_j$ defines the number of elements in the $j$-th box, then you want to count the $(a_1,\ldots ,a_M)\in  (\mathbb N \cup \{0\}) ^M$ such that $a_j\leqslant K$ for each $j\in\{1,\ldots,M\}$ and $\sum_{j=1}^Ma_j=N$. Then note that this number is just the coefficient of $x^N$ in the expansion of the polynomial $(1+x+x^2+\ldots +x^K)^M$, this is notated as $[x^N](1+x+x^2+\ldots +x^K)^M$.

For the general case it is just
$$
[x^N]\prod_{j=1}^M(1+x+x^2+\ldots +x^{K_j})
$$

For a way to handle this kind of problems, at least for simpler cases, take a look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2290090/probability-that-the-sum-of-k-dice-is-n/2290139#2290139). A good book about counting methods using generating functions is [this](https://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/DownldGF.html).