# How to determine the number of integer solutions to this particular case?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, summation, integers, constraints

> Consider the equation $$z_1 + z_2 + z_3 + z_4 + z_5 + z_6 = k$$ For:
>   $i = 1, \dotsc,6$ $z_i$ is a positive natural number and they must
>   satisfy the following: \begin{align} z_1 & \ge 4  \\ z_2 & \ge 10 \\
>  z_3 & \ge 12 \\ z_4 & \ge 18 \\ z_5 & \ge 6 \\ z_6 & \ge 30
> \end{align}
>
> (a) For what values of $k$ are there no solutions?
>   (b) Determine the
>   number of solutions for other values of $k$

Comment: Please add what you have tried so far to the question so that people on the site can help you solve your problem.

Comment: Can you not say anything at all about (a), wout? Can you not see that there's no solution for $k=-17$? for $k=100\sqrt2$? for $k=20$?

Answer (score 1):

(a) The minimal $k$ value is for $z = b$: 
$$
k = 4 + 10 + 12 + 18 + 6 + 30 = 80
$$
For smaller $k$ values there is no solution.

(b)

For $k = 80 + 1$ we have $6$ components to distribute the additional $1$ to.

For $k = 80 + 2$ we have $6$ possible choices for the first additional $1$ and again $6$ possible choices for the second additional $1$. However some of the choices lead to an indistinguishable result, like $(1,2)$ and $(2,1)$, so we have $(6^2 - 6)/2 + 6 = 15 + 6 = 21$ choices.

For $k = 80 + n$, $n \in \mathbb{N}$, it is the general combinatorial problem of putting $n$ identical objects into $6$ bins. See e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/47345/86776).
This gives 
$\binom{n+6-1}{6-1} = \binom{n+5}{5}$ 
choices.

Answer (score 1):

$(a)$ $^{k-(4+10+12+18+6+30)+(n-1)}C_{(n-1)}=^{(k-81+6)}C_{(6-1)}=^{(k-75)}C_5 \neq 0 $

For minimum one solution : $^{(k-75)}C_5=1 \implies (k-75)=5, \implies k=80$.

> So, solution is not possible only when $k<80$ for given conditions.

$(b)$ When restriction is not applied the number of solutions $=^{(k+(n-1))}C_{(n-1)}$.

If these conditions applied :

> Value of $k$ should be $k\geq 80$ for atleast one solution and $k$ should be integer.

[In how many ways can 20 identical balls be distributed into 4 distinct boxes subject?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/691823/in-how-many-ways-can-20-identical-balls-be-distributed-into-4-distinct-boxes-sub)