# Proper way to solve this arrangement of balls in boxes with certain conditions

Tags: combinations

Given $N$ boxes, with each box having maximum capacity to store and $M$ balls, find in how many ways can the balls be arranged in those boxes?

Example: $N=2$ such that their max capacity is $5$ and $5$ respectively, $M=3$.

Then answer is $4$: Possible arrangements are $(3,0) (0,3) (2,1) (1,2)$

Comment: Is there a typo here? How is M 3 if the max capacity is 5?

Comment: M is the number of balls . Max capacity of each of the box is 5 i.e you can place at most 5 balls in each of the box.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Let $x_i$ denote the number of balls in box $i$ for $i=1,2,\ldots,N$. Then you need to find the number of integer solutions of the equation $$x_1+x_2+\ldots+x_N=M$$ subject to $0\le x_i\le m_i$ where $m_i$ denotes the maximum capacity of box $i$.

You can see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/229430/how-many-integer-solutions-to-a-linear-combination-with-restrictions) for some ideas on how to proceed.

Comment: Isn't there any form of 2D recurrence evolving out of this to make the solution easier to compute?

Comment: See the link I posted. This is a standard problem in combinatorics and yes there are standard methods for easy compution, but they do not involve recurrence relations, as far as I know.