# Stars and bars with upper bound

Tags: combinatorics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I determine the number of unique hands of size H for a given deck of cards?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/146477/how-can-i-determine-the-number-of-unique-hands-of-size-h-for-a-given-deck-of-car)

There are **n** chocolates and **k** students. How many ways can it be distributed so that each student receives no more than **m** chocolates?

Assume that m<=n

Comment: [This answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/203839/12042) to another old question gives more explanation of the formula arrived at in the question to which I linked above.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I think that it would not be so bad to have the answer written for this question because it has the "right" level of generality for the problem.