# number of solutions for the equation

Tags: combinatorics

Given $r$ nonnegative integers $k_1, k_2, \ldots, k_r$.
What is the total number of integer solutions of the inequality
                     $$x_1 + x_2 + \dots+ x_r \ge 0 $$ 
such that $-k_1 \le x_1 \le k_1; -k_2\le x_2 \le k_2; \dots ; -k_r\le x_r \le k_r$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $y_i=k_i-x_i$ for $i=1,\dots,r$, and let $k=k_1+\ldots+k_r$, then you’re looking for non-negative integer solutions to $y_1+\ldots+y_r\le k$ subject to the conditions $y_i\le 2k_i$ for $i=1,\dots,r$. Now add an $(r+1)$-st variable $y_0$, and count the solutions to $y_0+y_1+\ldots+y_r=k$ in non-negative integers satisfying $y_i\le 2k_i$ for $i=1,\dots,r$.

Without the upper bounds this would be a standard [stars-and-bars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28probability%29) problem, and the answer would be $\binom{k+r}r$. With the restrictions it requires an [inclusion-exclusion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) argument that is rather messy. My answer to [this problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/146477/12042) covers the case in which the $k_i$ are all equal.