# Number of solutions over positive integers of $x_1 + x_2 + ... + x_n = S$ for $x_i \in [0, 25]$

Tags: combinatorics

How many solutions are there to $x_1 + x_2 + ... + x_n = S$ for given $S$ assuming that $0 \le x_i \le 25$? I can solve it when there are no constraints on $x_i$ other that $x_i$ must be non-negative.

Comment: what are the constraints on $n$ or what is its relationship with $S$?

Comment: This is a case for either "Inclusion-Exclusion" or "generating functions." Do you know either technique?

Comment: And yes, does $n$ vary, or are $S$ and $n$ fixed?

Comment: I've only heard about Inclusion-Exclusion principle, but don't know how this could be applied here. $n$ and $S$ may vary, I want to know how to solve general case, but you may assume that $S > n$

Comment: When I say that $n$ is fixed, I mean, you don't want the sum of all values $x_1+x_2=S, x_1+x_2+x_3=S, \dots$, but that you want to just know the count for one pair $S,n$.

Comment: Yours is actually a special case of the earlier question (and of [this one](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/146477/how-can-i-determine-the-number-of-unique-hands-of-size-h-for-a-given-deck-of-car) as well. You may also be interested in [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/553960/extended-stars-and-bars-problemwhere-the-upper-limit-of-the-variable-is-bounded), in which the different variables can have different upper bounds.

Comment: This is a $\infty$-plicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming $n$ fixed.

**Generating function approach**

Let $a_s$ be the number of solutions for $x_1+\cdots+x_n=s$ with $0\leq x_i\leq 25$. Then:

$$\begin{align}\sum_{s=0}^\infty a_sz^s &= (1+z+z^2+\cdots+z^{25})^n\\
&=\frac{(1-z^{26})^n}{(1-z)^n}
=(1-z^{26})^n\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\binom{i+n-1}{n-1}z^i
\end{align}$$

Using $(1-z^{26})^n=\sum_{j=0}^n \binom{n}{j}(-1)^jz^{26j}$, you get:

$$a_S = \sum_{j=0}^{n} (-1)^j\binom{n}{j}\binom{S+n-1-26j}{n-1}$$

**Inclusion-Exclusion approach**

Let $A$ be the set of all solutions $x_1+\cdots+x_n=S$, with only the condition that the $x_i\geq 0$.

Let $A_i$ be the elements of $A$ with $x_i\geq 26$.

Then you want the size of $A\setminus(A_1\cup A_2\cup\cdots\cup A_n)$. This is ideal for inclusion/exclusion.

You get:

$$\begin{align}|A\setminus(A_1\cup\cdots\cup A_n)|=&|A|\\&-(|A_1|+|A_2|+\cdots+|A_n|)\\
&+(|A_1\cap A_2|+|A_1\cap A_3|+\cdots +|A_{n-1}\cap |A_n|)\\
&\vdots\\
&+(-1)^n|A_1\cap A_2\cap \cdots \cap A_n|
\end{align}$$

This will turn into the same formula as above. Each term in each row is the same, and there are $\binom{n}{j}$ terms in the $j$th row (starting with $j=0$ at $|A|$.)