# Stars & Bars w/ global maximums - (Combinatorics)

Tags: combinatorics

The "Stars & Bars" technique has proven very helpful in solving various combinatoric problems I have been dealing with. I have been able to tweak it slightly to fit various examples, but one form still elludes me:

Is there a formulaic answer when there is a general/global maxium?

Ex: if you have 15 balls; how can you sort them into 10 bins, if each bin is only capable of holding 4 balls maximum? (and how would the amount of combinations change if each bin could hold a max of 5 or some other number)

I have a feeling there is a formula out there to encompass or help with this but have been unable to find it. Thank you very much for any help you may have.

Comment: In general it’s messy; see [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/146477/how-can-i-determine-the-number-of-unique-hands-of-size-h-for-a-given-deck-of-car).