# Coefficient of $x^{27}$ in $(1-x^{10})^6/(1-x)^6$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, combinatorics, power-series

It's been a while since I have been playing with these so excuse me if it is too obvious.

How can I represent

$$ f(x) = \frac{(1-x^{10} ) ^6}{(1-x)^6} $$

as sum of powers of $x$

I am especially interested in the coefficient in front of $x^{27} $ in that sum.

The book I am reading gives this coefficient as obviously being

$${32 \choose 5}- {6 \choose 1} {22 \choose 5}+{6 \choose 2}{12 \choose 5}$$

but I don't know where this comes from.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: First take off the powers of $6$ from the whole fraction. Then see if the formula $\frac{1-r^n}{1-r}$ looks at all familiar…

Comment: @Jam Yeah it looks familiar, I know what it is. I am intentionally giving this short representation here. But when I take it to power 6... how do I know which number I get in front of  $x^{27}$?! Or in front of any $x^k$?

Comment: how can you get $27$ from adding $6$ non-negative integers together?

Comment: @Jam Not sure what you mean here. Sorry. What 6 non-negative numbers?

Comment: @Jam Oh, I see. Well I tried that too. Leads me to 2 Diophantine equations which I don't find too obvious either. But it is not 6 numbers, it is 10 numbers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First from the geometric series
$$
\frac{1}{1-x}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n
$$
combined with repeated differentiation yields that
$$
\frac{1}{(1-x)^6}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\binom{n+5}{5} x^n\tag{1}
$$
(for $|x|<1$, if you don't want to deal with formal series). The binomial theorem implies that
$$
(1-x^{10})^6=1-6x^{10}+\binom{6}{2}x^{20}-\binom{6}{3}x^{30}+\binom{6}{4}x^{40}-\binom{6}{5}x^{50}+x^{60}\tag{2}.
$$
We want the coefficient of $x^{27}$ in the product of (1) and (2). We get an $x^{27}$ term  from the products $1\times x^{27}$, $x^{10}\times x^{17}$ and $x^{20}\times x^{7}$. In particular the coefficient is then
$$
\binom{27+5}{5}-6\binom{17+5}{5}+\binom{6}{2}\binom{7+5}{5}.
$$

Comment: Aaahhh... Wow. That is nice. Exactly the trick I was looking for. Many thanks.

Answer (score 4):

As an alternative recall that

$$(1-x^{10} )=(1-x)(1+x+x^2+\ldots+x^9)$$

therefore

$$f(x) = \frac{(1-x^{10} ) ^6}{(1-x)^6}=(1+x+x^2+\ldots+x^9)^6$$

then we can evaluate the coefficient for $x^{27}$ by the [**stars and bars method**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) by the equivalent problem, discussed [**here**](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/98065/505767), of the numbers of way to distribute $b=27$ balls in $c=6$ container with no more than $n=9$ balls in any container that is

$$N(b,c,n)=\sum_i(-1)^i\binom{c}i\binom{b+c-1-i(n+1)}{c-1}=$$

$$=\binom{27+6-1}{5}-\binom{6}{1}\binom{27+6-1-(9+1)}{5}+\binom{6}{2}\binom{27+6-1-2(9+1)}{5}=$$

$$={32 \choose 5}- {6 \choose 1} {22 \choose 5}+{6 \choose 2}{12 \choose 5}$$

Comment: OK that's where I came from... I am intentionally giving this short representation here.

Comment: @peter.petrov refer to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem

Comment: I know this too. But how do I calculate the exact number? It is too big non-human calculation.

Comment: How did they came up with this nice expression for the coefficient before $x^{27} $?!

Comment: This does not give a human-computable way to find the coefficient  $x^{27}$ in $f(x)$.

Comment: @peter.petrov You are right my first suggestion wasn't conclusive, I've updated with the same idea and performing the computation by stars and bars method.

Comment: @MikeEarnest You are right, I've updated with the constrained stars and bars method for the final counting.

Comment: Thank you very much for this alternative solution.

Comment: @peter.petrov You are welcome! Bye

Answer (score 4):

Expand out the numerator with the binomial theorem:
$$
(1-x^{10})^6=1-\binom{6}1x^{10}+\binom{6}2x^{20}-\dots
$$
We could do more terms, but since you want the $x^{27}$ coefficient this is all we will need.

The numerator is being multiplied by $(1-x)^{-6}$, which can be expanded using the generalized binomial theorem, sometimes called Newton's binomial theorem:
$$
(1-x)^{-6}=\sum_{k\ge 0}\binom{-6}k(-x)^k=\sum_{k\ge 0}\binom{6+k-1}kx^k
$$ 
Finally, since we are multiplying these, we have to find all ways of choosing monomials from both so their powers add up to $27$. We can only get powers of $0, 10$ or $20$ from the first factor, so the second factor must contribute either $27,17$ or $7$. Adding up these three contributions gives
$$
1\cdot \binom{6+27-1}{27}-\binom{6}1\binom{6+17-1}{17}+\binom{6}2\binom{6+7-1}{7}
$$

Comment: Thanks. That also seems exactly what I needed.