# Number of partitions with limited cardinality

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations, integer-partitions, set-partition

We are given $k$ urns labeled from $1$ to $k$. What is the number of ways to put $n$ indistinguishable balls into the $k$ (distinct) urns, given that each urn has a limited capacity equal to $c$, namely the maximum number of balls that can be put in the same urn?

Comment: Is it suppose to have $c < n$?

Comment: From the statement of the problem, $c \leq k$

Comment: @trueblueanil it is not $k.$ It has to be $n$ because $n$ represents the number of balls. Also, even if $c > n$ we could still have a limited capacity for each urn

Comment: The answer to the earlier question to which I linked uses generating functions; you can also use inclusion-exclusion, as noted [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/98065/how-many-ways-can-b-balls-be-distributed-in-c-containers-with-no-more-than).